# Preserving data in one form when submitting a second form

Tags: php, forms

I have a page with two forms that is generated with PHP.

The first part contains text boxes, a submit button and a clear button.

The second form is just a button called "Add more text boxes" so the user can add more to his form if he needs to.

The problem is when I click the "Add more rows" which loads another page which changes a value.

This value then affects the original page when it reloads causing more text boxes to get created.

The problem is that I lose all the data that was entered.

Is there any way to preserve the data when the user clicks "Add more rows"?.

Here's a screenshot of my page.

[image: Screen shot of page]

Thanks

Comment: You would need to add the additional rows via Javascript instead of reloading the page and doing this on the server.

Comment: @brucebat - Have you considered using jQuery to do this? The other option would be to set the `value` of the fields as you're creating them if a value exists in `$_POST` or `$_GET`.

Comment: @Michae Mior - If I use javascript how does my other php page which gets the posts know how many textboxes there are? Thanks

Comment: You can name your input fields as an array. If you give them names such as `InputName[3]`, you can iterate over `$_POST` or `$_GET` as an array.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it without js than you put all in one form. When you click button to add row all entered data will be available in $_POST or $_GET so you can fill form with existing data and add a row when generating new page.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should use javascript to dynamically add new rows w/out making new requests to the server and loading new pages.  But if you want to keep it javascript free.  If it's all the same php script just controlled by conditions, just use the `$_POST['variable']` values as the `value="$_POST['variable']"` in your fields.  If it's handled through multiple scripts, you can use a session variable to pass the data from one page to the next.